# Updating users in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to update my user profile programmatically, but I get an error saying only an administrator can update that field. I am the administrator on my laptop, where I am running SharePoint on Windows 7. Can someone tell me how I can get SharePoint to know that I am the administrator so I can update my and other profiles? I've checked SharePoint and I'm listed as the owner of the site. Also, if there is a way to update these things in the interface, I'd be glad to do that instead of code.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
        string sAccount = "Wanna\\be";
        UserProfile u = profileManager.GetUserProfile(sAccount);
        u[PropertyConstants.HomePhone].Value = "9999999999";
        u[PropertyConstants.CellPhone].Value = "9999999999";
        u[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Value = "Wanna";
        u[PropertyConstants.LastName].Value = "Be";
        u[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value = "wannabe@mycompany.com";
        u.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code using RunWithElevatedPrevilges
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // Implement code here
});

Comment: I added the RunWithElevatedPrivileges and am still not able to edit the profile of a user. I get the error: Property Not Editable: This property can only be modified by an administrator. How can I fix this? The error shows when modifying the first or last name and when trying to commit it.